# How to use the auto created table by the DbContext (OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder))

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I Created a Many to Many Relationship between two tables

The table **MoviesHashTags** was auto created by the DbContext.

I want to be able to send a query to MoviesHashTags table with Linq

The problem is that I don't have any model of it and the DbContext not giving me any option to use it. for example something like that :

`_db.MoviesHashTags.Select(i =>i.Id).Where(i => i.HashTagId==3)`

Is there a way to do this without `_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("QUERY")`

**Example:**

I want to take all the Id's that have HashTagId=3

**TABLE MoviesHashTags:**

[image]

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**TABLE Movies:**

```
[DataContract]
public class Movie 
{
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    *
    *
    *
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<HashTag> HashTagsCollection { get; set; }

public Movie()
{
    HashTagsCollection = new HashSet<HashTag>();
}
```

**TABLE HashTag:**

```
[DataContract]
public class HashTag
{
    [DataMember]
    public long HashTagId { get; set; }
    *
    *
    *
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<Movie> MoviesCollection { get; set; }

    public HashTag()
    {
        MoviesCollection = new HashSet<Movie>();
    }
```

**DbContext:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().
    HasMany(c => c.HashTagsCollection).
    WithMany(p => p.MoviesCollection).
    Map(
        m =>
       {
        m.MapLeftKey("Id");
        m.MapRightKey("HashTagId");
        m.ToTable("MoviesHashTags");
        });
 }
```

**ANSWER: Thanks to @DigitalD**

`db.Movies.Where(m => m.HashTagsCollection.Any(h => h.HashTagId == hashTag.HashTagId)).Select(m => m.Id);`

Comment: Does it give any error to you if you try to map it manually in the "OnModelCreating" like you did with the entity "Movie"?

Comment: I didn't understand your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq should be able to handle the following:

```
var HashTag = _db.HashTags.Find(3); //or whatever method you need to get a single hashtag
var Movies = _db.Movies.Where(m => m.HashTagsCollection.Contains(HashTag))
                 .Select(m => m.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the directions! I wrote what I used in the main question.
Thanks!

Comment: @Ofear You can skip a step then and put the value directly in place of the `hashTag.HashTagId` as such: `db.Movies.Where(m => m.HashTagsCollection.Any(h => h.HashTagId == 3)).Select(m => m.Id);`